# Change the width of the search bar in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

Is it possible to change the width of the search bar in VSCode?
I.e. the typical dropdown selection menu opening when using 'Go to file...' (workbench.action.quickOpen) or switching recent files (workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup).

My current motivation for this is to be able to fully see long file names which are truncated.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately VSCode doesn't have configuration for this property but it is planned.

There is a small workaround for this if you don't have time to wait.

1. Install [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui)
2. Set property `"customizeUI.stylesheet": { ".quick-input-widget": "width: 1000px !important; left: calc(50% - 200px);" }` in settings.json
3. Reload window

source from
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85374#issuecomment-629982777

Comment: Note that this does not work when running vs-code from snap on Ubuntu, because it is then not possible to grant permission to monkey-patch which is required by the "customize UI" extension. See https://github.com/iocave/monkey-patch/issues/5

Comment: Also, note after 1.74 Customize UI [stopped working completely](https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui/issues/156).

Comment: Do not use this extension, it irrevocably breaks VS Code, and is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) extension now that Customize UI is deprecated.

Follow the instructions from the extension and add this to your custom.css file:

```css
.quick-input-widget {
    width: 90% !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looked promising but does not work for me...

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you can change the width of the find widget now:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiline-support-and-find-widget-resizing

Unfortunately, from what I can tell, you cannot yet:

- Increase the height of the find widget
- Increase the font-size of the text displayed within the find widget ([requested feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101064))
- Position the find widget somewhere else (eg the bottom of the editor)

I am coming from Sublime Text editor and am finding it a bit of a "What is this, a center for ants!" (Derek Zoolander) experience.

**Edit:**

Just figured out some sort of workaround for the `font-size` within the find widget:

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, you increase the size of everything, including the text editor.

However, if you also have `Mouse Wheel Zoom` enabled in `Settings`, you can zoom back out in the text editor, and it does not effect the elements that were resized via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, including the find widget.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The search bar I'm asking about in the original question is that associated to the palette, not the find widget.