How to increase the "search by file name" search bar size in VS Code?
I want to increase my search by file name bar size in order to view both file name with file path in visual studio code. Is there any way to see both file and its path fully while search for files?
I tried with Custom CSS and JS Loader, but it doesn't working. So could you suggest the way to increase the bar size for the same.


related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76449706/11107541

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896453/change-the-width-of-the-search-bar-in-vscode

This is the subject of feature request issue ticket Option to widen the command palette #85374 (yes, the title says "command palette", but the command palette and the Quick Open menu just use the underlying Quick Pick mechanism as far as I know).
I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
